# JPM: How to personalize a toggle button tooltip label

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox-addon, jpm

I have a toggle button in my addon. I want to personalize the `CSS` inside tooltip label who appear when you hover the button.

---

Below example with **Firebug** icon tooltip label

[image]

---

This is my toggle button

```
var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "S1",
  label: "Ultimate",
  icon: {
    "16": "./16-disabled.png",
    "32": "./32-disabled.png",
    "64": "./64-disabled.png"
  }
});
```

I have try a lot of solutions but never works.

```
label: "<strong>Ultimate</strong>" // Result: <strong>Ultimate</strong>
label: "<b>Ultimate</b>" // Result: <b>Ultimate</b>
label: "<div style='font-weight:bold'>Ultimate</div>" // Result: <div style='font-weight:bold'>Ultimate</div>
```

Just the `\n\r` work

```
label: "Ultim\nate" // Result: Ultim
                               ate
```

Comment: While possible, this is not directly supported by the Add-on SDK. Do you really want to go through the effort for *just* making the text **bold**?

Comment: Bold is just for example. I want to show diffferent informations when the addon is active. If possible make a hr line or other. I dont want color, background, etc...

Comment: It's really an all-or-nothing proposition. There are two methods of doing a tooltip. The simple one gives you text. The more complex one gives you almost anything. The more complex one is not supported by the Add-on SDK API. You can do it within an SDK add-on, but would have to write it as XUL, perhaps putting in an `<iframe>` to use just HTML, which would be more SDK-like.

Comment: Thank you. I will see XUL and other.